# Springboot 3.1.1 is not working with opentelemetry-javaagent

Tags: java, spring-boot, trace, open-telemetry, jaeger

I'm using spring boot version 3.1.1. In order to enable tracing for this application, i want to use opentelemetry-javaagent.jar as the javaagent like mentioned in [this setup document](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/#setup).

I'm also running jaeger service in my local and used following environment variables to publish the traces

```
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://jaeger-local:4317
OTEL_EXPORTER=otlp
OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=service-name
```

I'm trying to run my server with following command.

```
java -javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -jar my-service.jar
```

I can see the traces published to the jaeger service fine but all of my requests are failing with 404 error as shown in the below picture. Is there anything I'm missing here. If I remove the `javaagent` while running my service, the same API works fine.

[image]

Comment: what happens when you do `curl http://localhost:5000/health` - If it also returns 404, then the health endpoint is not exposed or `/actuator/health`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76636649/springboot-3-1-1-is-not-working-with-opentelemetry-javaagent

Comment: Java agents are notorious for causing this sort of problem. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33921 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33974 for examples. I would check that you're using an up-to-date version of the agent and there it doesn't have any known incompatibilities. You may also want to consider using Spring Boot 3.x's built-in observability rather than using the java agent for instrumentation.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, thanks for your input. It gave me the right direction to follow. After updating the java agent to the latest version, the problem got solved.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Do you have a full example of SB 3.x observability? I am currently using the JavaAgent which is successfully producing trace, metrics and logs over grpc. However, the collector isn't giving me an good logs. If I take the payload and post via http port, I get 200 Partial Success but nothing in the collector?